# How To Fix Login Form In PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Whenever I try to login with the simple page I made. But there is a problem with the lookup to see if that information is in the database or not. All it requires is you to login in with username and password.

Here is the html form :

```
<p> Login </p>

<form action='login.php' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='username'/><br>
<input type='password' name='password'/><br>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'/>

</form>
```

Here is the script for that form :

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

include ("connect.php");

if ($username && $password) {

    // Info Is Provided
    $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
    $numrow = mysql_numrows($queryget);
    if ($numrow != 0) {

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        echo "You Have Been Loggend In. | <a href='members.php'>Go To The Members Page</a>";

    } else {

        echo "Your Username Was Not Found";

    }

} else {

    echo "You Did Not Provide All OF The Neccesary Information.";
    include ("index5.php");

}


 ?>
```

Can you figure why it won't let me Login?

Comment: What happens when you try to log in?  Does it say Username not found?

Comment: Please don't type every word with a capital first letter.

Comment: Yes and ok. it say that the username was not found.

Comment: please use `mysql_error` to find if database have error: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_error.asp

Comment: I turned error_reporting off

Comment: Offtopic but.. unless this is for home/internal use you really should hash your passwords.

Comment: So I turned error reporting on and it said this Notice: Undefined index: username and Notice: Undefined index: password. What does this mean?

Comment: I know i just working on something for another thing. i use md5 hashing.

Comment: as @joke_Sense10 told you should use `$_ISSET` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: You shouldn't use MD5 for password hashing either.

Comment: Try putting `session_start();` right under the `<?php`. And also, it would be better to use `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])` and `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])` in terms of security.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
$numrow = mysql_numrows($queryget);
```

To:

```
$numrow = mysql_num_rows($queryget);
```

And also use [**isset**](https://www.php.net/isset) function in the if condition:

```
if(isset($username) && isset($password)){
```

Comment: Change to  if (isset($username) && isset($password)) {

Comment: replace the line under     include ("connect.php");

Answer (score 0):

You probably had whitespace after the closing ?>

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

session_start();

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

include ("connect.php");

if (isset($username) && isset($password)) {

    // Info Is Provided
    $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
    $numrow = mysql_num_rows($queryget);
    if ($numrow != 0) {

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        echo "You Have Been Loggend In. | <a href='members.php'>Go To The Members Page</a>";

    } else {

        echo "Your Username Was Not Found";

    }

} else {

    echo "You Did Not Provide All OF The Neccesary Information.";
    include ("index5.php");

}

?>
```

Comment: Nope, Still Not Working.

Comment: Does it still say username not found? Are you sure that username is in the database and the username/password combination are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Hi the problem you are having may have something to do with the version of PHP you are using, MySQL is outdated and does not function on the latest versions, it have changed to MySQL which is similar so its defiantly worth learning. The code below is similar to yours only I have removed the include to connect.php and replaced it with MySQLi. I have also made a change to the query limiting only one item to return.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


$Connect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$database);

if (isset($username) && isset($password))
{
    // Info Is Provided
    $queryget = mysqli_query($Connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'     AND password='$password' LIMIT 1");
    $numrow = mysqli_num_rows($queryget);
    if ($numrow == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        echo "You Have Been Logged In. | <a href='members.php'>Go To The Members Page</a>";
    }
    else 
    {
    echo "Your Username Was Not Found";
    }
} 
else 
{
    echo "You Did Not Provide All OF The Neccesary Information.";
    include ("index5.php");
}
?>
```